# Laravel Chumper Zipper how to extract without specific folder name

Tags: php, laravel, zip

I have a zip file with this format:

```
test.zip
    |- test/
        |- test.txt
        |- test2.txt
```

I'm able to extract using this:

```
$zipper = new Zipper();
$zipper->make('test.zip')->folder('test')->extractTo('foo'); //extracts contents of test folder inside zip to foo directory
```

How do I extract contents without specifying the folder name inside zip?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

$zipper = new Zipper();

$zipper->make('path/of/your/file/test.zip')->extractTo('foo');

make sure both paths/locations (zip file and extract) are ok. it works for me.